# ProjectItem.moveBin() not working correctly Extends Script (Adobe)

Tags: javascript, extendscript

im currently developping a script with extends script which is a javascript-similar script language, that we use to automate tasks in Adobe's Softwares (here its premiere pro)
Here is what my code is doing :
-i import files from a folder in my computer
-then i put them in a bin in my prpro project
-and for each of this file i create a bin with the file and a sequence

**My problem is that the last file is not move in a bin**

here is my code

```js
    root = app.project.rootItem
    newFilesPath = "C:/Path"
    newFilesBin = root.children[0]
    
    app.project.importFiles(newFilesPath, true, newFilesBin, false)
    
    app.project.save()
    
    newFilesBin = root.children[0]
    
    for(i=0; i<newFilesBin.children.numItems; i++){
        newFile = newFilesBin.children[0]
        name = newFile.name
        
        newBin = root.createBin(name)
        file.moveBin(newBin)
    }
```

So if i put several file in the path it doesnt move the last file instead of moving every files

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :

i just change the parameters of my `for` loop

```
for(i=-1; i<newFilesBin.children.numItems+1; i++)
```

I dont exatly know why its working but it works